# g++ compiler throwing errors with basic commands to compile

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, g++

I'm currently using the g++ compiler on Mac OS X, trying to run the command

```
g++ rt.cpp –o rt
```

For some strange reason, it throws the following errors:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '–o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'rt'
```

My gcc compiler works fine with the C projects I've written, so Xcode didn't entirely fail to download it. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Wait you are calling g++ and you are getting clang errors?

Comment: On Mac OS X, g++ is soft linked to clang (Thanks Obama/Apple!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a dash character (–) instead of a minus (-) before of the 'o'.

Try

```
g++ rt.cpp -o rt
```